# Not able to assign ethers to account in private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, private-blockchain

I am running a testnet with init property for genesis block i am able to create an account and its working fine only problem is that i am not able to assign any pre ethers to an account which i was able to do in previous implementation of genesis flag while running. Any one can please tell how to do it in this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, put the balance you want for an address in the genesis block. Here's an example:

**myGenBlock.json**

```
  {
      "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
      "difficulty": "0x20000",
      "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "timestamp": "0x00",
      "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "extraData": "",
      "gasLimit": "0x2fefd8",
      "alloc": {
        "dbdbdb2cbd23b783741e8d7fcf51e459b497e4a6": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "e6716f9544a56c530d868e4bfbacb172315bdead": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "b9c015918bdaba24b4ff057a92a3873d6eb201be": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "1a26338f0d905e295fccb71fa9ea849ffa12aaf4": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "2ef47100e0787b915105fd5e3f4ff6752079d5cb": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "cd2a3d9f938e13cd947ec05abc7fe734df8dd826": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "6c386a4b26f73c802f34673f7248bb118f97424a": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "e4157b34ea9615cfbde6b4fda419828124b70c78": {
          "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376"
        },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
          "balance": "1"
        },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
          "balance": "1"
        },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
          "balance": "1"
        },
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": {
          "balance": "1"
        }
      }
    }
```

Assign the balance you want to an address but first make sure you have generated a private key for it otherwise you won't be able to use the balance.

To initialize the private test net run:

```
mkdir myTestNet
geth --datadir myTestNet init myGenBlock.json
```

Next whenever you want to use it just point **geth** to the directory by adding the arguments:

```
--datadir myTestNet
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for gaining Ether:

- Pre-allocating through genesis file
- Mining

**Genesis file:**
This can be done using the `alloc` field in the genesis file.

- Create a genesis file first
- Create accounts using `geth --datadir path/to/directory/ account new`
- Allocate ether to this account as mentioned by @Sebi
- Now start the node using this genesis file (`init`), `--datadir` and a unique `--networkid`

**Mining:**

- After starting the node and creating accounts using `geth --datadir path/to/directory/ account new` or `personal.newAccount("<password>").`
- Start mining from this node using `miner.start(1)` where 1 = no. of mining threads
- Now, all this mining reward will be allocated to the coinbase account
- You can then transfer this Ether to other accounts