# How to preallocate multiple accounts with ether for geth --dev chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, private-blockchain

I'm trying to set up a private chain with geth using `--dev` that has several accounts with lots of ether. It seems unclear if this is possible anymore according to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2294).

Here's what I tried on geth 1.4.x and 1.5:

```
geth --datadir data --dev --password <(echo -n foobar) account new
geth --datadir data --dev --password <(echo -n foobar) account new
geth --datadir data --dev --password <(echo -n foobar) account new
```

Then init like so:

```
geth --datadir data --dev --password <(echo -n foobar) init custom.json
```

Then running geth with mine:

```
geth --datadir data --dev --password <(echo -n foobar) \
  --unlock 0,1,2 \
  --verbosity 6 \
  --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain '"*"' --nodiscover \
  --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice 0
```

Then I use `curl` to check the balance of the accounts. Result is `0x0`.

If I remove the `--dev` option there is balance, but it takes forever as it then uses the real DAG. I don't want that as this if for testing.

**How to best get multiple preallocated accounts with lots of ether for a private dev chain?**

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add more Ether on a private blockchain](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/how-to-add-more-ether-on-a-private-blockchain)

Comment: @BokkyPooBah yes that works but it's for a private chain without `--dev`

Comment: `--dev` is just some additional configs - see https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/flags.go#L125-L128 and https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/cmd/utils/flags.go#L724-L744 . maxpeers=0, listenaddr=:0,whisper is enabled, powtest is true and something to do with the olympic genesis block and the gas price. What you can do otherwise is use `--dev`, mine and move the ETH to your other account. There does not seem to be a convenient way to set preallocated accounts using the `--dev` setup.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah yes I know it's possible to move ether but as this used to work I'd like to know maybe it still does or if not why it isn't anymore :)

Comment: From https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases, `With the coming of Geth 1.4 we've deprecated the --genesis <json_file> flag and replaced with a geth init <json file> sub command. This means that you'll no longer be able to mix the destructive --genesis flag with other flags.`

Comment: @BokkyPooBah yes I have read that too. I use `init` with a custom genesis that has accounts as I would like them in `alloc`. I.e. first I run `new account` and then I adjust the custom genesis and then run `init`. No balance if I have the `--dev` flag.

Comment: I've retracted the close vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to assign ethers to account in private chain](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/not-able-to-assign-ethers-to-account-in-private-chain)

Answer (score 2):

It is suppossed to be done by editing your custom genesis file of your testnet.
adding something like:

```
//The genesis file
"alloc":{
        "address":{
                  "balance": "1000000"
                  }
        }
}
```

Source: https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

Comment: This does not work anymore for dev...hence my question.

Comment: Ok, if i find any other solution for this, i'll tell you.

Comment: Tried a bit ago and it worked for me. 
Check that you are starting the testnet properly with your custom genesis file.

Comment: I don't use testnet... `--dev` and private chain

Comment: using `--dev` causes your private to start with a preconfigured set of options. So no chance to preallocate as you are not using a custom Genesis.json file but a preconfigured one.

Comment: it used to work and was documented but changed. the reason `--dev` is interesting is because of the lack of DAG...

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

1. Initialise geth in dev mode with the `--` flag

   `geth --dev --allow-insecure-unlock`

   *Never do this in mainnet mode.*
2. Attach a web3 js console
3. Run this to create 10 unlocked accounts and fund them from the default account:

   `for (i=0;i<10;i++){
       a = personal.newAccount('pwd')
       personal.unlockAccount(a,'pwd',0) 
   web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:eth.accounts[i+1],value:1000000000000})
   }`